# Avoiding duplicate transactions when retrying

Tags: transactions

When using [sendAndConfirmTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#sendAndConfirmTransaction) with a commitment, or pre-flight commitment level of `finalized` and it fails, is it guaranteed to be safe to retry the function call again?

The solana [cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html#customizing-rebroadcast-logic) explains a method of avoiding duplicate signed transactions by comparing the last valid blockheight used.
I'd prefer not having to do this. Would the method I explained above be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to define "fails":

- If it returns an error on the transaction with a finalized commitment, it is safe to retry given the commitment guarantees
- Another failure scenario is the awaiter timing out, older @solana/web3.js package version are not safe on that regard as it awaits a set amount of time regardless of the blockhash validity.

Use instead a recent @solana/web3.js package version and make sure `sendAndConfirmRawTransaction` function uses the `BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy` stategy which does
what the cookbook recommends to do, for you, for free.

Link to the source code of the function:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/f57f228126b01eec2a48cc39711252dfacf04462/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts#L40-L48

Answer (score 2):

What makes rebroadcasting a transaction "safe" or not is whether or not the same instructions are being resigned with a new recent blockhash.  This should *never* be done so long as a previously broadcast transaction's recent blockhash is extant.  Instead it can be simply rebroadcast until it expires via `sendAndConfirmRawTransaction`, as suggested by @arowana.  You will likely need to query and set the recent blockhash by hand as well as sign and serialize.  The "convenience" function `sendAndConfirmTransacion` does so much behind the scenes as to be considered harmful in all but the most trivial example code.

Comment: So...
`sendAndConfirmRawTransaction` is better than `sendAndConfirmTransacion` because `sendAndConfirmRawTransaction`  has some type of retry functionality built-in ?